# How to set the Border/Background Color for Grid/Row Column

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to have every row/cell of grid with distinctive color with border thickness and color in code than XAML,how can i do it.

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
    <Border.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>
    <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  Text="Account Number :"   Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
</Border>
```

Above is XAML code,for my Grid Row,I am trying do it similarly in C# code.How do i add border property to row or cell.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll have to name your border, lets say you set `x:Name=myBorder`.

Than in the code-behind you can do: `Grid.SetRow(myBorder, 1);`. Similarly for column you set: `Grid.SetColumn(myBorder, 1);`.

For more info you can refer to the msdn article: [How to: Create a Grid Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752271.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could help you. I changed the row colors from the C# code using canvas, before adding the content to the grid I added a canvas in every other row and changed the canvas background color and then added my content as usual. Regards.